# Can Kubernetes pods expire after successful completion?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a job with a large number of completions, so hundreds of pods are created and eventually move into `COMPLETED` status.

Is there a way to expire the pods as they complete so I don't end up with a massively long list of completed pods?

We can do this for jobs using:

```
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 300
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
```

But I haven't seen a way to do that for the pods created by the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're left behind on purpose and you have to clean them up manually. We have a custom cleaner job which removes them after 7 days.

> When a Job completes, no more Pods are created, but the Pods are not
> deleted either. Keeping them around allows you to still view the logs
> of completed pods to check for errors, warnings, or other diagnostic
> output. The job object also remains after it is completed so that you
> can view its status. It is up to the user to delete old jobs after
> noting their status.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-termination-and-cleanup